# How to make use of auto-renew feature in flutter firebase - In App Purchase service

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, in-app-purchase

I'm making use of in-app-purchases (the subscription one) in flutter and for the backend, I'm relying on firebase

What I'm doing is.. when a customer makes the purchase, it adds the expiration date on firebase but how to handle the auto-renew feature, how would I listen to it and re-update the expiration date on auto-renewal day

```
   // listening to the incoming purchases

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadPlans();

    InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream.listen((event) {
      for (var element in event) {
        if(element.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased){ // executed on successful purchase
          widget.userModel.expirationDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 30)); // add 30 days from the today day
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(widget.firebaseUser.uid).update(widget.userModel.toMap());
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: have anyone found out the solution for it cause i also dont know how to handle autorenewal purchase date and expiry date.